# iPhoneからMacのlocalhostにアクセス

Tags: ios, mamp

iOSアプリ開発で、実機でデバッグをしたいです。 
サーバサイドはMAMPでローカル上に作成しており、iPhoneからMacのlocalhostにアクセスしようとしています。 
下記のURLを参考にMacのローカルホスト名を使用しいます。 
http://qiita.com/shymst/items/4517a9b904c2c7f908ed

ただ、アクセスしても

「Not Found
 The requested URL/ was not found on thie server」

と表示されてしまいます。 
ブラウザのアイコン自体はMAMPのものが見えているのでアクセス自体はできているのかな？といった状態ですが、ここからわかりません 
どうしたらいいのでしょうか・・・よろしくお願いします。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/51330

Answer (score 1):

`Not Found The requested URL/ was not found on thie server`はapacheのサーバーが返しているはずですし、アイコンまで表示されているのであればアクセス自体はできています。

MAMPの動作確認は`アプリケーション > MAMP > htdocs`ディレクトリの中に`info.php`を作成してください。
ファイルの中身は以下のコードです。

```
<?php phpinfo();
```

http://**.local/info.phpにアクセスするとPHPの情報が確認できます。